# Как найти по значению ключа объект?

Tags: javascript, json

json:

```js
let data = 
[ 
 {
  "room":{ 
   "flamingo":0
    }
  },
  {
  "park":{ 
   "flamingo":65
    }
  }
]
```

Можно ли с помощью значения найти объект?

Comment: Уточните, пожалуйста, с помощью какого именно значения? Известно только значение или также вложенные ключи, где это значение должно быть? В общем, лучше привести примеры — что искать и что должно быть найдено.

Comment: В этом примере надо искать по кол-во фламинго помещение.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Так подходит?

```js
let data = [
  {
    room: {
      flamingo:0
    }
  },
  {
    park: {
      flamingo:65
    }
   }
];

const count = 65;

const placesWithFlamingo = data.filter((obj) => {
  const [[placeName, place]] = Object.entries(obj);
  return place.flamingo === count;
});

console.log(placesWithFlamingo);
```

Comment: А вот если бы у меня было несколько помещений, где было бы 65 фламинго, то что бы мне тогда использовать? [Тут говорят,](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find) что `find`  возращает только первый подходящий, а мне нужны все.

Comment: Тогда можно использовать `filter()` вместо `find()`, тогда вы получите или пустой массив, или массив с подходящими элементами. Изменил код под эти условия.

Answer (score 0):

Анастасия, я Вам настоятельно реккомендую пересмотреть структуру Вашей переменной data. Она подозрительно "не складная". Но, если уж на то пошло - вот ответ на Ваш вопрос:

```
const findObjectByFlamingo = (data, neededFlamingo) => data.find(obj => obj[Object.keys(obj)[0]].flamingo === neededFlamingo)
```

Посмотрите описание функции find тут:
https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find

Comment: ты сделал свою реализацию [`find`](https://developer.mozilla.org/ru/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/find)

Comment: Блин, виноват. Поправил